# How has the support for integration within the EU changed during the COVID-19 pandemic?

Tags: european-union, covid-19, public-opinion, europe

I'm interested in any surveys studying the popular support for EU and EU integration done in the EU memberstates within the period of the coronavirus. How has the COVID-19 pandemic affected the EU's citizens stances towards the European integration?

Comment: Somewhat old news: https://www.euractiv.com/section/coronavirus/news/italians-least-satisfied-with-eus-coronavirus-response/ More recently, although not quite frames as you ask https://www.ecfr.eu/publications/summary/together_in_trauma_europeans_and_the_world_after_covid_19

Comment: @Fizz Thanks. I don't think the first survey answers the question but the second one could. Unfortunately, the questions are formulated badly (of course people disliking the EU will say their stance has strengthened and vice versa) so I don't think its conclusions are reliable.